# AWS SES Timeout issue with laravel 8

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I have configured AWS SES as stated on the docs and used these command to test the smtp but go this response;

commands:

php artisan tinker
Mail::raw('hello world', function($msg){$msg->to('email@gmail.com')->subject('test mail');});

Response:

Swift_TransportException with message 'Connection could not be established with host email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com :stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to tcp://email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:587 (Operation timed out)'

Any help, pls

Comment: Where is this code running? On your local computer? On an EC2 instance in a VPC?

Comment: @MarkB testing from my local machine at the moment